# Python: Unable to locate element: selector

Tags: python, google-chrome

I try to open a browser and click on a button by using a python script
My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get('xxx')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#softGateBox > div.button_softgate > a')
button.click()
```

The website opens. It waits 5 seconds and then I see the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#softGateBox > div.button_softgate > a"}
```

What can be wrong? I use chrome to inspect the button and I perform a right click and click copy selector.

Comment: better show real url instead `"URL"` then we can check this page,

Comment: maybe start with shorter selector `#softGateBox` and see if program can find it.

Comment: @furas thanks for your help, but didn't work

Comment: so if it can't find `#softGateBox` then CSS is incorrect.

Comment: @furas I've added the URL

Comment: this element is inside `<iframe>` which is treated as separated page so you have to find this <iframe> and `switch_to_frame()` before you can search inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is few problem with this page

- element is inside `<iframe>` so you have to find `<iframe>` and `switch_to_frame()` before you can search element
- `<iframe>` is in external `<iframe>` so first you have to find external `<iframe>` and `switch_to_frame()` before you start to searching internal `<iframe>`
- on small monitor element is invisible so Selenium can click it. You have to scroll page to element and then you can click it.

.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome() #'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

browser.get('https://www.facebook.com/SparColruytGroup/app/300001396778554?app_data=DD722A43-C774-FC01-8823-8016BFF8F0D0')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

iframe = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#pagelet_app_runner iframe')
browser.switch_to_frame(iframe)

iframe = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#qualifio_insert_place iframe')
browser.switch_to_frame(iframe)

button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#softGateBox > div.button_softgate > a')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", button)

button.click()
```

**BTW:**

There can be other `<iframe>` on page so you can't direclty do `selector('iframe')`.

Internal frame have `id` but it changes every time you load page so you can't do `selector('iframe#some_uniqe_id')`